# How to uninstall Homebrew?

Tags: macos

I’ve got some problems with the package manager, [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). I can’t find how to remove it!

Is it safe to remove whole `/usr/local`? Homebrew was installed somewhere in that directory.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

They provide an official [uninstall script](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew) you can download and run:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`

[Homebrew once recommended an older script](https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223), also linked [in their FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew).

Here is a copy of the old script, for historical purposes:

```
cd `brew --prefix`
git checkout master
git ls-files -z | pbcopy
rm -rf Cellar
bin/brew prune
pbpaste | xargs -0 rm
rm -r Library/Homebrew Library/Aliases Library/Formula Library/Contributions 
test -d Library/LinkedKegs && rm -r Library/LinkedKegs
rmdir -p bin Library share/man/man1 2> /dev/null
rm -rf .git
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew
rm -rf /Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

This should also revert your `/usr/local` folder to its pre-Homebrew days.  See the [Homebrew installation wiki](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation) for more information.

*Note*: You may also need to remove `~/.homebrew` as well. If you happen to have `~/.rvm`, then you should delete `~/.rvm/bin/brew`.  If any of your brew package had brew services that are running, you should turn them off.  If any packages installed their own libraries (like Python's pip) you'll have to uninstall those manually.

Comment: thank you so much! i've googled so hard, but even't bothered to look for uninstallation actions in installation manual! ;D

Comment: Note that the instructions have changed over time, and also been moved to the Homebrew FAQ
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/FAQ/1ef6c2cf55db89252949c7bb2908abe093a3414a

Comment: Following these commands deleted almost all my files on `Desktop`, `Documents` and 'Downloads`. It messed up my git too. Please help!

Comment: rm -rf Library/Taps

Comment: and also: rm -rf /Library/Caches/Homebrew

Comment: Look also for LaunchAgents:

/Users/$username/Library/LaunchAgents

Comment: If the first line of this script fails it will try to delete whatever is in your pasteboard. That could be a lot of your data.

Comment: @ade: :/ Too Late.

Comment: "This should also revert your /usr/local" which of the scripts does this refer to? Will this also uninstall all packages installed by brew (my guess is no).

Comment: I don't understand why I installed this crap. When trying uninstalling it, it asks me if I want to delete following files - then a list comes where it also wants to delete the entire `/usr/local/Library/`. Wtf? It contains other files too, like MySQL stuff. It seems that homebrew was installed directly to `/user/local/`. WTF?!?

Answer (score 50):

Homebrew provides an [uninstall script located here](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew).

Just run the following in the OSX terminal:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

Comment: good one, just simple solution

Comment: Better imho is to install homebrew cleanly in the first place.
[Here](https://medium.com/macoclock/a-clean-approach-to-installing-homebrew-d17c797fb045) is how: `>> git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew ~/git/brew`, then run it from there - all packages will be residing there then.

Comment: The Ruby uninstaller has been deprecated; they now recommend use of this Bash command: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"`

Comment: Thanks @StackOverflown, I just updated the broken link and uninstall command.

Comment: After running this command, I got below output ==> Homebrew uninstalled!
The following possible Homebrew files were not deleted:
/usr/local/.com.apple.installer.keep
/usr/local/Frameworks/
/usr/local/Homebrew/
/usr/local/bin/
/usr/local/etc/
/usr/local/include/
/usr/local/lib/
/usr/local/opt/
/usr/local/share/
/usr/local/var/
You may wish to remove them yourself.

Comment: do we need to remove these manually as well ? Why doesn't uninstallation script removes them ?

Comment: the best 1 without Ruby installation

Comment: It now tries to remove the entire /usr/local directory. Really? Isn't there "quite a few other things" in there? This brew uninstall script no longer looks safe to run

Answer (score 10):

Also note that homebrew changes group to 'staff' and gives write access to group for

- `/usr/local`
- `/usr/local/bin`
- `/usr/local/include`
- `/usr/local/lib`
- `/usr/local/sbin`
- `/usr/local/share`

In order to put back these directories in their original states do:

```
sudo chown root:wheel <directory> ; sudo chmod 755 <directory>
```

for each one or if you don't have fancy owners /  rights:

```
sudo chown -R root:wheel /usr/local ; sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local
```

Comment: I cannot confirm this. My `/usr/local` and its Homebrew-created subdirs are owned by my user with the `admin` group.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1173223), it uninstalls homebrew and associated caches, provided you installed brew to the default directory.

Comment: how do you use a gist?

Comment: @ninja08 Click on the link. Open a terminal window. Copy all of the gist's text into the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I recently [made a script to handle this case](https://gist.github.com/SteveBenner/11254428). It completely removes Homebrew, and has CLI options like silent/verbose and force modes, as well as mode that returns the location of your Homebrew installation.

Answer (score 0):

The ruby script now prints:

```
Warning: The Ruby Homebrew uninstaller is now deprecated and has been rewritten in
Bash. Please migrate to the following command:
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

So the right way to uninstall is apparently to run:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

Answer (score -3):

There might be other files in `/usr/local` you might need you might be able to user a different PM (Package Manager) to remove the current PM.

Comment: I'm unclear as to what this answer means. What's a PM?

Comment: PM = Package Manager