# Uninstalling Homebrew messed up git

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, git, homebrew

I uninstalled Homebrew using https://superuser.com/a/203740.

After running the above commands, I can't find `.bashrc` and `.bash_profle`. All files are gone from `Documents` , `Desktop` and `Downloads` :'(

When I do git status on `/Users/ava` it shows:

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

... all the files which are in /Users/ava
```

history

```
 113  cd `brew --prefix`
  114  rm -rf Cellar
  115  brew prune
  116  rm `git ls-files`
  117  rm -r Library/Homebrew Library/Aliases Library/Formula Library/Contributions
  118  rm -rf .git
  119  rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew
  120  sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local
  121  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
  122  brew doctor
```

What just happened?

Comment: You probably have them in Time Machine somewhere, either on an external drive or Time Capsule or in [local snapshots](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4878). Try restoring your folders from there. I'm not sure if Time Machine can show hidden files like .bashrc; if so, you should follow [these instructions](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/os-x/quick-tip-revealing-hidden-files-in-os-x/) before going into Time Machine to restore those files.

Answer (score 1):

If git was tracking all the files under /Users/ava then the

```
rm `git ls-files`
```

command will have deleted them all (which I imagine is what your `git status` output is telling you.

If the files you are talking about aren't in that list then I'm not sure which of those rm commands might have caused the problem.

Comment: Is there any way to undo this? Why did it delete my files from `Desktop`, `Documents`, `Downloads` and `.bashrc_profile`?

Comment: Do you see those files listed in the git output? Actually that's a question too. Why does git still think you have a repository if you removed the .git directory? If the files aren't listed in the git output then you have to hope that they are in the OS X trash (or similar location). Failing that you are talking about data recovery and that's not necessarily a simple task. If you do need the data recovery route you should stop using the drive/computer as soon as possible (every time the computer needs to use the disk it has a chance of stomping over your deleted data).

Comment: No! `document/desktop/downloads/.bashrc/.bashrc_profile` files dont show up on git status.

Comment: The full paths to those files are `/Users/ava/Documents`, `/Users/ava/Desktop`, `/Users/ava/.bashrc`, etc.? And `git status` from in `/Users/ava` doesn't list them? I'm assuming it does list other (brew related) files from under `/Users/ava` though?

Comment: Yes they were all under `/Users/ava`. No `git status` does not list them. It shows few of my projects under it but I am not very sure what all went missing and what is remaining. The above mentioned are definitely gone.

Comment: I'm still not sure what could have caused the files to get deleted but it doesn't look like you have any easy recovery route (unless they are in the OS X trash). You probably need to start looking into deleted file recovery methods (and possibly using a recovery service depending on how important the files that are missing are). Someone with more expertise in file recovery and/or OS X might have something more useful to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks fishy: `sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local`

Are you an admin? Run `groups` to find out. I don't know what your original `/usr/local` ownership settings were, but here's mine (and I regularly use git and brew):

```
lovelace% ls -dl /usr/local
drwxrwxr-x  18 root  admin  612 Aug  5 15:30 /usr/local
```

It looks like `root:admin` should be the owner of `/usr/local`. Try:

```
sudo chown -R root:admin /usr/local
```

Comment: Part of the point of Homebrew is that you don't need to be root. `brew doctor` will warn you if you can't write to `/usr/local`, and recommend you chown the directory back to your user account.

Comment: `groups` - 906175167 com.apple.access_screensharing everyone _appstore netaccounts _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin _lpoperator _developer

Comment: `sudo chown -R root:admin /usr/local` gives

WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.