# Uninstalling Homebrew messed up git

Tags: git, bash, unix, terminal, homebrew

I uninstalled Homebrew using https://superuser.com/a/203740.

After running the above commands, I can't find `.bashrc` and `.bash_profle`.

When I do `git status` on `/Users/ava` it shows:

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

... all the files which are in /Users/ava
```

`history`

```
  113  cd `brew --prefix`
  114  rm -rf Cellar
  115  brew prune
  116  rm `git ls-files`
  117  rm -r Library/Homebrew Library/Aliases Library/Formula Library/Contributions
  118  rm -rf .git
  119  rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew
  120  sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local
  121  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
  122  brew doctor
```

Also noticed that all files are missing from `Documents` and `Downloads`

What just happened?